# how to add commas to number on different devices?

Tags: android

I develop in eclipse and I have a strange problem.
i tried to add commas to number so i add this code:

```
s = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(count);
```

I checked it on many emulators and evreything work fantastic.
Now I published the application and in some devices the comma just does not appear.
Please help!

Comment: Is it possible that the missing commas are on devices in other regions?

Comment: What do you mean?
i have just one xml layout and just one java activity....

Comment: Not all countries/regions group digits with commas. Some use periods, others don't group their digits at all.

Comment: Maybe you're right.....
So what should I do?

Comment: If you *must* have a consistent number format, you could hardcode the locale. `s = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance( Locale.US ).format( count );`

Comment: I'll try and I'll give you an answer.
Thank you very much for your support!!

Comment: I turned it into an answer -- if this solves your problem, please accept it so it could help others. If not, please let me know, and I'll remove it, so as not to confuse the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance()` is dependent on the default locale of the device, and not all locales will have digit-grouping by comma. In some parts of the world, periods are used, others use apostrophes, while yet others use no grouping at all.

In order to get consistent results of comma-grouped integers, specify the locale as follows:

```
s = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance( Locale.US ).format( count );
```

Comment: It worked!!!!
Thank you!
You do not understand how you helped me, you are the best!